# How can I use the gradle-release-plugin to auto-increment the minor - not the incremental

Tags: gradle-release-plugin

I'm using the gradle-release-plugin successfully in jenkins with the option gradle.release.useAutomaticVersion=true; however, it is incrementing the incremental and i'd like to increment the minor....

1.14.0
want to increment to 1.15.0, rather than 1.14.1

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure how the increment should work.

```
release {
    versionPatterns = [
        /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d)$/: { Matcher m, Project p -> m.replaceAll("${m[0][1]}.${(m[0][2] as int) +1}.${m[0][3]}") }
    ]
}
```

I think this should do the trick. It should match your current version via the regex pattern

```
/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d)$/
```

And writes the new version by

```
m.replaceAll("${m[0][1]}.${(m[0][2] as int) +1}.${m[0][3]}")
```

where the second group is incremented by 1

Didn't tested the code

Comment: Perfect. The below worked for me: /[.]*\.(\d+)\.(\d+)[.]*/: { Matcher m, Project p -> m.replaceAll(".${(m[0][1] as int) + 1}.0") }                                             I